# LINQ using values already calculated in a select new

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I wasn't able to find anything on the Internet...

I have the query shown below which does a "Select new {...}". Inside the "Select new" there are two fields of interest which are "numbPlays" and "numbCompleted".

I'm trying to get in the "select new" an additional field called "lvlSuccessRate" which is basically a simple division of: "numbCompleted" / "numbPlays"

Is there a way I could reference these two fields instead of calculating them again? I haven't found the way to do it yet.

Thanks in advance :D

[image: Current code]

Added the full query as text as Narish suggested:

```
var query = from lvlData in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevels
                            where (lvlData.DateDeleted == null)
                            select new {
                                Id = lvlData.Id,
                                isPrivate = lvlData.IsPrivate,
                                thisUserOwnsLvl = thisUserID == lvlData.FkUserCreatedBy ? true : false,
                                FkUserCreatedBy = lvlData.FkUserCreatedBy,
                                DateCreated = lvlData.DateCreated,
                                LvlTitle = lvlData.LvlTitle,
                                LvlDesc = lvlData.LvlDesc,
                                isLikedByUser = (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsLikes
                                                 where (tbl.IsLike == true) && (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId) && (tbl.FkUser == thisUserID)
                                                 select tbl).Count(),
                                numbLikes = (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsLikes
                                             where (tbl.IsLike == true) && (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId)
                                             select tbl).Count(),
                                numbPlays = (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsPlays
                                             where (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId)
                                             select tbl).Count(),
                                numbCompleted = (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsCompleteds
                                                 where (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId)
                                                 select tbl).Count(),
                                bestTime = (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsBesttimes
                                            where (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId)
                                            orderby tbl.BestTime
                                            select tbl.BestTime).First(),
                                bestTime_fkUserId = (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsBesttimes
                                                     where (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId)
                                                     orderby tbl.BestTime, tbl.DateLastUpdated
                                                     select tbl.FkUser).First(),
                                bestMoves = (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsBestmoves
                                             where (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId)
                                             orderby tbl.BestMoves
                                             select tbl.BestMoves).First(),
                                bestMoves_fkUserId = (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsBestmoves
                                                      where (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId)
                                                      orderby tbl.BestMoves, tbl.DateLastUpdated
                                                      select tbl.FkUser).First(),
                                lvlSuccessRate = ((from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsCompleteds
                                                  where (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId)
                                                  select tbl).Count() / (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsPlays
                                                  where (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId)
                                                  select tbl).Count()),
                                popularityRateLastWeek = (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsPlays
                                                          where (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId && tbl.DateLastUpdated >= lastWeekValue)
                                                          select tbl).Count() * 0.0035 +
                                                          (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsLikes
                                                           where (tbl.IsLike == true && lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId && tbl.DateLastUpdated >= lastWeekValue)
                                                           select tbl).Count() * 0.0065,
                                popularityRateLastMonth = (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsPlays
                                                          where (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId && tbl.DateLastUpdated >= lastMonthValue)
                                                          select tbl).Count() * 0.0035 +
                                                          (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsLikes
                                                           where (tbl.IsLike == true && lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId && tbl.DateLastUpdated >= lastMonthValue)
                                                           select tbl).Count() * 0.0065,
                                popularityRateLastYear = (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsPlays
                                                           where (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId && tbl.DateLastUpdated >= lastYearValue)
                                                           select tbl).Count() * 0.0035 +
                                                          (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsLikes
                                                           where (tbl.IsLike == true && lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId && tbl.DateLastUpdated >= lastYearValue)
                                                           select tbl).Count() * 0.0065
                            };
```

Comment: Please post this code block as a code snippet and *not* a screenshot. Use comments to clearly provide whatever annotations the red line drawings are meant to provide

Comment: Also, your best bet is to evaluate these as separate variables above the block, and then simply reference the variables. The use of `.Count()` is going to be evaluated lazily, meaning the LINQ query will run as many times as your invoke it under its variable, so you can force the count by casting the result IEnumerable to a List or an array, and then counting that collection. This way the LINQ expression is evaluated only once and those variables will just be simple `int` vars you can reference

Comment: @Narish: Assuming `_context` is a query provider (like an Entity Framework context), this whole query will probably be translated into a big SQL statement, rather than actually invoking `Count()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `let` keyword to create variables within your query, then reference those variables within your select.

```
from lvlData in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevels
where (lvlData.DateDeleted == null)
let numbPlays = _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsPlays
    .Count(tbl => lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId)
let numbCompleted = _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsCompleteds
    .Count(tbl => lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId)
...
select
{
    ...
    numbPlays,
    numbCompleted,
    ...
    lvlSuccessRate = numbCompleted / numbPlays,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution I've been searching for.
NOTE: the commas before the "Select" at the end of each let are wrong.

Comment: Good catch. Fixed.